# I need to reset a program in python. Or maybe stop a loop

Tags: python

I either need to restart this or end the loop. CMU only has a limit of 2000 or so shapes. And all the loops for those arcade style lights are creating a stupid amount of shapes. So I either need a way to just reset the whole program or stop the looping. It's the loops that have no color after the death part

```
    app.background='lightBlue'


collectorsBin = Rect(240, 0, 160, 150, opacity=50, borderWidth=5, border='black')

moodCounter = Label(0, 325, 210, size=30, fill='white')

returnArrow = Line(230, 330, 170, 330, arrowEnd=True, visible=False)

loser = Label('LOSER!!!!', 200, 200, size=50, visible=False)

redo = Line(370, 370, 160, 370, arrowEnd=True, visible=False)

rileyArea = Rect(240, 280, 160, 120, opacity=50, borderWidth=5, border='black')



anger= Group(
            Rect(200, 220, 50, 55, fill='red'),
            Rect(200, 250, 50, 25, fill='white'),
            Rect(200, 260, 50, 15, fill='brown'),
            Polygon(225, 250, 250, 240, 250, 250, 200, 250, 200, 240, 225, 250, fill='white'),
            Line(250, 250, 200, 250, opacity=10),
            Circle(212, 232, 8, fill='white'),
            Circle(238, 232, 8, fill='white'),
            Line(225, 228, 250, 225, fill='red', lineWidth=5),
            Line(225, 228, 200, 225, fill='red', lineWidth=5),
            Line(220, 243, 230, 243, lineWidth=5, fill='white'))
            
rileyFace = Circle(200, 200, 30, fill='blanchedAlmond')
rileyEyes = Group(Circle(185, 200, 10, fill='white'),
                    Circle(215, 200, 10, fill='white'))
                    
normalHair = Group(Polygon(208, 183, 190, 186, 179, 197, 175, 227, 162, 227, 162, 185, 173, 170, 191, 165),
                    Polygon(191, 165, 199, 165, 218, 172, 230, 190, 229, 210, 225, 191, 206, 182))
                    
normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')

riley=(rileyFace, rileyEyes, normalHair)

rileyFace.centerX=315
rileyFace.centerY=350
rileyEyes.centerX=315
rileyEyes.centerY=350
normalHair.centerX=315
normalHair.centerY=350

sadness = Group(Rect(170, 210, 60, 60, fill='ivory'),
                Circle(200, 200, 30, fill='royalBlue'),
                Polygon(230, 190, 200, 180, 200, 200, 180, 220, 160, 230, 170, 180, 200, 160, 235, 187,
                fill=gradient('royalBlue', 'dodgerBlue', 'blue', start='top')),
                Circle(210, 200, 8, fill='white'),
                Line(200, 190, 220, 195, fill='royalBlue', lineWidth=8))
                
happiness = Group(Circle(200, 200, 50, fill='lightGoldenrodYellow'),
                Circle(200, 200, 50, fill='gold', opacity=50),
                Circle(223, 200, 16, fill='white'),
                 Circle(178, 200, 16, fill='white'),
                Oval(200, 228, 20, 35, fill='white', rotateAngle=70),
                Oval(197, 223, 20, 30, fill='lightGoldenrodYellow', rotateAngle=70),
                Oval(197, 223, 20, 30, fill='gold', rotateAngle=70, opacity=50),
        Polygon(156, 217, 163, 173, 192, 180, 210, 180, 200, 175, 228, 174, 250, 190, 255, 178, 252, 168, 230, 150, 200, 145,
        180, 150, 160, 152, 150, 160, 145, 185, 147, 200, fill=gradient('deepSkyBlue', 'darkBlue')),
    Rect(185, 247, 35, 75, fill='lightGoldenrodYellow'),
    Rect(185, 247, 35, 75, fill='gold'),
    Polygon(190, 247, 195, 260, 205, 260, 215, 247, 220, 247, 225, 330, 180, 330, 185, 247, fill='white'))
    
    

happiness.width/=1.5
happiness.height/=1.5

fear = Group(Polygon(200, 200, 205, 235, 215, 235, 220, 200, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Circle(200, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Circle(220, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Oval(210, 225, 25, 15, fill='white', border='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Rect(205, 235, 10, 40, fill='white'),
            Rect(205, 275, 10, 20, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Arc(221, 196, 20, 20, 300, 180, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Arc(198, 198, 20, 20, 230, 180, fill='mediumSlateBlue'),
            Circle(210, 235, 3, fill='crimson'),
            Polygon(210, 235, 217, 228, 220, 237, fill='crimson'),
            Polygon(210, 235, 203, 240, 200, 230, fill='crimson'))
            
disgust = Group(Polygon(185, 225, 190, 243, 210, 243, 215, 225, fill='limeGreen'),
            Rect(190, 243, 20, 3, fill='lawnGreen'),
            Polygon(190, 246, 185, 265, 215, 265, 210, 246, fill='limeGreen'),
            Circle(200, 200, 30, fill='lightGreen'),
            Circle(185, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Circle(215, 200, 10, fill='white'),
            Rect(175, 185, 50, 10, fill='lightGreen'),
            Polygon(200, 190, 185, 198, 175, 195, 175, 225, 163, 233, 163, 228, 170, 228, 165, 175, 193, 168, 223, 172, 233, 200, 
                    fill=gradient('lawnGreen', 'darkGreen')))
                    

    
    
emotions = Group(anger, sadness, fear, disgust, happiness)

loserLabel = Label('Loser Loser', 200, 200, size=50, visible=False)

death = Label('X  X', 200, 200, size=20, visible=False)
                
disgust.centerX=36
disgust.centerY=57

happiness.centerX=39
happiness.centerY=197

fear.centerX=47
fear.centerY=327
                
sadness.centerX=120
sadness.centerY=58

anger.centerX=116
anger.centerY=189
def onMouseDrag(mouseX, mouseY):
    if(sadness.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        sadness.centerX=mouseX
        sadness.centerY=mouseY
    
    if(anger.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        anger.centerX=mouseX
        anger.centerY=mouseY
        
    if(happiness.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        happiness.centerY=mouseY
        happiness.centerX=mouseX
        
    if(fear.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        fear.centerX=mouseX
        fear.centerY=mouseY
        
    if (disgust.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
        disgust.centerX=mouseX
        disgust.centerY=mouseY
        
        
        
        
def onMousePress(mouseX, mouseY):
    eyes='white'
    hair = gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
    mood = 0
    
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(anger):
        eyes = 'red'
        hair ='red'
        mood = 1
        rileyEyes.visible=True
        normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
        death.visible=False
        loserLabel.visible=False
        app.background='lightBlue'
        
        for i in range(20):
            Circle(10 + 20 * i, 390, 10, fill='red', visible=True)
        
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(sadness):
        eyes = 'blue'
        hair ='blue'
        mood = 1
        rileyEyes.visible=True
        normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
        death.visible=False
        loserLabel.visible=False
        app.background='lightBlue'
        
        for i in range(20):
            Circle(10 + 20 * i, 390, 10, fill='blue', visible=True)
            
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(disgust):
        eyes = 'green'
        hair ='lawnGreen'
        mood = 1
        for i in range(20):
            Circle(10 + 20 * i, 390, 10, fill='green', visible=True)
        
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(happiness):
        eyes = 'gold'
        hair =gradient('deepSkyBlue', 'darkBlue')
        mood = 1
        for i in range(20):
            Circle(10 + 20 * i, 390, 10, fill='gold', visible=True)
        
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(fear):
        eyes = 'mediumSlateBlue'
        hair ='mediumSlateBlue'
        mood = 1
        for i in range(20):
            Circle(10 + 20 * i, 390, 10, fill='mediumSlateBlue', visible=True)
            
            
        
    if collectorsBin.containsShape(emotions):
       emotions.visible=False
       app.background='red'
       normalHair.visible=True
       collectorsBin.visible=False
       rileyArea.visible=False
       moodCounter.visible=False
       rileyFace.centerY=200
       rileyFace.centerX=200
       rileyEyes.centerY=200
       rileyEyes.centerX=200
       rileyEyes.visible=False
       for i in range(20):
           Circle(10 + 20 * i, 390, 10)
       for i in range(20):
           Circle(10, 10 + 20 * i, 10)
       for i in range(20):
           Circle(10 + 20 * i, 10, 10)
       for i in range (20):
            Circle(390, 10 + 20 * i, 10)
       normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
       death.visible=True
       app.background='red'
       loserLabel.visible=True
       death.centerX=200
       death.centerY=100
       rileyFace.centerX=200
       rileyFace.centerY=100
       normalHair.centerX=200
       normalHair.centerY=100
       returnArrow.visible=True
       
       if (returnArrow.contains(mouseX, mouseY)==True):
           disgust.centerX=36
           disgust.centerY=57
    
           happiness.centerX=39
           happiness.centerY=197
    
           fear.centerX=47
           fear.centerY=327
                    
           sadness.centerX=120
           sadness.centerY=58
           
           emotions.visible=True
           for i in range(20):
                Circle(10 + 20 * i, 390, 10, visible=False)
           for i in range(20):
                Circle(10, 10 + 20 * i, 10, visible=False)
           for i in range(20):
                Circle(10 + 20 * i, 10, 10, visible=False)
           for i in range (20):
                Circle(390, 10 + 20 * i, 10, visible=False)
           app.background='lightBlue'
           normalHair.fill=gradient('paleGoldenrod', 'darkGoldenrod', start='left')
           rileyEyes.fill='white'
           loserLabel.visible=True
           death.centerX=200
           death.centerY=100
           rileyFace.centerX=315
           rileyFace.centerY=350
           rileyEyes.centerX=315
           rileyEyes.centerY=350
           normalHair.centerX=315
           normalHair.centerY=350
           rileyEyes.fill='white'
           
        
   
   
        
    rileyEyes.fill=eyes
    normalHair.fill=hair
    moodCounter.value=mood
```

It's the death black light loop. Is there a way to make the loop stop or make the app itself reset?

Comment: The chunk at the bottom is the bit I'm having a problem with

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the loop you are referring to. However if you want to exit a loop in python you use the break keyword:

```
while(True):
   #do stuff
   if conditionToStop:
      break
```